# Change axes position in line chart

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to get a chart in ionic application where the y-axis on the right

Here is what i have done

My code:

```
@ViewChild('barChart', {static: true}) BarChart: ElementRef;

this.bars = new Chart(this.BarChart.nativeElement, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Viewers in millions',
                    data: [2.5, 3.8, 5, 6.9, 6.9, 7.5, 10, 17],
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(88, 172, 230, 0)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(88, 172, 230)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(88, 172, 230)',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgb(88, 172, 230)',
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    yAxisID: 'right-y-axis',
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {}
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'right-y-axis',
                            type: 'linear',
                            position: 'right'
                        }]
                }
            }
        });
```

[image: chart1]

but i am getting unexpected numbers on the left [-0.1 , -0.5 .... ]

What i need to do:

[image: chart2]

So I need to remove grid's lines and those numbers on the left, as well as change the x-axis to reverse , so it starts from the right not the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong brackets. And you don't need an additional axis, just change the position of the one you have.

```
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                            position: 'right',
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false
                            }
                    }]
                }
            }
```

Comment: How to change from where linking between two axes start ? , I mean that i need the blue bubbles start from right

Comment: Oh, I didn't read that. You can use `labels.reverse()`and `data.reverse()`.